# Solving a differential equation for all values of $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the equation

$
y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{{y^{\prime}}^{2}}{y}+\frac{2y^{\prime}}{x+1}+\frac{y^{\prime}}{x(x+1)}=\frac{x+1}{6xy^{2}}
$

I was successful to solve the above equation for $x\ll{1}$ and $1\ll{x}$, but is it possible to solve this equation for all values of $x$.

Comment: can you say something about your ode?

Comment: I think I'm stumped.  If that second term had a coefficient of 2 or that last term had $y$ rather than $y^2$ in the denominator, I could do it.

Comment: hey Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, this equation was written as $\frac{x}{x+1}\frac{d^{2}(y^{2})}{dx^{2}}+\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^{2}}\frac{d(y^{2})}{dx}=\frac{1}{3y}$ and $y$ is related to the Ricci scalar(R) by $y=a/R$

Comment: might be easier if solve for $y^2$ first

Comment: Dylan, how can I do that? could you show me please?